# In ViewModel binds value with another

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, bind

I'm using Kendo JQuery with MVVM.

I would like to automatically change the value of the a variable ("label") when another variable changes ("optionId").

This is my VieModel:

```
  var vm = kendo.observable({
    optionId: '',
    label: ( this.optionId == 'Spaghetti' ? "Pasta selected" : "Animal selected" ),

    setOption: function( event ) {

      var value = event.currentTarget.value;

      this.set("optionId", value );
      //this.set("label", this.optionId == 'Spaghetti' ? "Pasta selected" : "Animal" );

    }
  });
```

If I remove the commented line, it works. But that's not what I want because I would have to add that line in every method.

I thought I could write:

```
label: ( this.get("optionId") == etc... )
```

but I can't. I believe this would work.

Here is an example on Kendo Dojo.

https://dojo.telerik.com/agewIWAk

Many thanks.

Comment: The value set to label in the object definition will remain until you update it and in a way or another you will have to update it sometime. You can create a method like `updateLabel()` with that condition inside and call it wherever you want., so you won't need to use that thernary everytime. [Like this](https://dojo.telerik.com/agewIWAk/6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution, from Telerik forum:

https://www.telerik.com/forums/in-viewmodel-binds-value-with-another